# i want to add backgroud image and when i click play button start video from zero seconed i used chewie package flutter

Tags: flutter

> tried to solve this issue
> what should  do

> used chewie package for flutter video player
> **what Should I Do To Solve This Proplem**

[image: this is code and emulator photo]

Answer (score 0):

Attach a listener to Chewie controller listen to the player states

Use Stack widget to overlay button and image as per your requirement.
On button click play video via controller.play(). And listener will update the state on (state == PlayerState.playing){ showImageAndButton = false;}
same on pause or stop { showImageAndButton = true;}
then setState() to update your widget. This is only pseudo code hope you get the idea

Comment: can you write it m code my method in the photo